In a navbar how can I extend the dropdown menu horizontally across the width of the page container?
Currently, when I hover over an item in the navbar, a horizontal drop-down menu opens like this (note the width of the drop-down menu):

What would I like to achieve?
I would like to widen the dropdown menu horizontally like in the next photo, but only desktop version. I would like the dropdown menu to be as wide as the container (the one that Bootstrap already uses with the container class) that I am already using in my navbar and that I will also use throughout the body of the site.
In the photo (photomontage/collage) I am inspecting the navbar with Chrome so as to highlight the navbar container to give you an idea of ​​how wide I would like the dropdown menu to be.

Can you help me and show me how to get it? I have tried several attempts, but I failed.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item.dropdown");

  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    dropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
      if (menu) menu.style.display = "flex";
    });

    dropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
      if (menu) menu.style.display = "none";
    });
  });
});
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Navbar */

.navbar {
  background-color: #000033;
  padding: 0 !important;
  /* Imposta il padding verticale invece dell'altezza */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Stile logo e testo del brand */

.logo {
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.brand-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1;
}

.fondazione {
  font-size: 0.80em;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.28em;
}

.surname {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}


/* Rettangolino colorato sotto le voci della navbar */

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* Gestisce lo spazio tra i link */
  line-height: normal;
  /* Usa la line-height di default */
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  /* Altezza del rettangolo */
  background-color: #459439;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Allineato al bordo inferiore */
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}


/* Rimozione della freccia dropdown */

.nav-link.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown orizzontale */

.dropdown-menu-horizontal {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000033 !important;
  padding: 20px !important;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 97% !important;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal:hover {
  color: #d4d4ff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Mostra il menu a tendina al passaggio del mouse */

.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* Responsive per dispositivi mobili */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Navbar con logo e link -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark mb-0">
  <div class="container align-items-stretch">
    <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
      <img src="img/..." alt="Logo" class="logo">
      <div class="brand-text">
        <span class="fondazione">AAAAAAA</span>
        <span class="surname">XXXX</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto h-100">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="fondazioneDropdown">COMPANY</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-horizontal" aria-labelledby="fondazioneDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 1"> Example 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 2"> Example 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 3"> Example 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




The way of setting the full width of the viewport of an element that has a position of absolute is to use: width: 100vw and then centering horizontally with the left property like this: left: calc(50% - 50vw). But in your case, I am not sure why it is not working properly. Unfortunately, can't figure it out right now. Sorry.

Add the Bootstrap class position-relative to the container and position-static to the dropdown.
Add the class w-100 to the dropdown-menu.
Finally the vertical view for the mobile version:
/* Responsive per dispositivi mobili */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
       padding-top: 20px;
       padding-bottom: 20px;
   }

   .dropdown-menu-horizontal {
       flex-direction: column;
   }
}



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item.dropdown");

    dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
        dropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
            const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
            if (menu) menu.style.display = "flex";
        });

        dropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
            const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
            if (menu) menu.style.display = "none";
        });
    });
});
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Navbar */
.navbar {
    background-color: #000033;
    padding: 0 !important; /* Imposta il padding verticale invece dell'altezza */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Stile logo e testo del brand */
.logo {
    height: 80px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.brand-text {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1;
}

.fondazione {
    font-size: 0.80em;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.28em;
}

.surname {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

/* Rettangolino colorato sotto le voci della navbar */
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px; /* Gestisce lo spazio tra i link */
    line-height: normal; /* Usa la line-height di default */
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px; /* Altezza del rettangolo */
    background-color: #459439;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Allineato al bordo inferiore */
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/* Rimozione della freccia dropdown */
.nav-link.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown orizzontale */
.dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000033 !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
    min-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 97% !important;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal:hover {
    color: #d4d4ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Mostra il menu a tendina al passaggio del mouse */
.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/* Responsive per dispositivi mobili */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu-horizontal {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>


    <!-- Navbar con logo e link -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark mb-0">
        <div class="container align-items-stretch position-relative">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
                <img src="img/..." alt="Logo" class="logo">
                <div class="brand-text">
                    <span class="fondazione">AAAAAAA</span>
                    <span class="surname">XXXX</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto h-100">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="fondazioneDropdown">COMPANY</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-horizontal w-100" aria-labelledby="fondazioneDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 1"> Example 1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 2"> Example 2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 3"> Example 3</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 7</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>




There is a problem in your code. The green selection rectangle has moved. In your code the green selection rectangle is almost attached to the items (for example Company) almost as if the word was underlined. In my original code the green selection rectangle was positioned lower on the bottom edge of the navbar. Can you please correct this? (as it was in my original question code)

The problem is already in your posted code. If I copy your code and run it, the same problem is there.

You're right, I didn't notice. I must have copied the code that was suggested to me in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79129133/css-in-a-navbar-how-can-i-extend-the-dropdown-menu-horizontally-across-the-widt in which they already solved the problem of the green selection rectangle.
I corrected the code in my question. I also leave you a working jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/xjashmb4 that is the same as the code in my correct question. I apologize. Can you correct your code based on what I showed you? Thanks

I have adjusted the answer.

Thanks. Now I'm going to sleep. Tomorrow i'll watch carefully, and let you know.

After having already voted your answer, I accept it as an answer. Thank you very much :)

You can modify the CSS position of the main menu item to 'static', so the absolute position of the submenu it will be related to the main nav .navbar (full width), or in this case the navbar container (.navbar .container) wich is set to position:relative. Then you can set the absolute position of the submenu I've added these lines to make it work that way (only for the first menu). This rule will affect only desktop screen width (>786px)
@media (min-width: 769px){
  .navbar .container{
    position: relative;
  }

  .navbar-nav > .nav-item{
    position: static;
  }

  .navbar-nav > .nav-item:first-child > div.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

Edit: I've added position:relative to the .navbar .container to make it the same with of the navbar container.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item.dropdown");

    dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
        dropdown.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
            const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
            if (menu) menu.style.display = "flex";
        });

        dropdown.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
            const menu = this.querySelector(".dropdown-menu-horizontal");
            if (menu) menu.style.display = "none";
        });
    });
});
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



/* Navbar */
.navbar {
    background-color: #000033;
    padding: 0px 0; /* Imposta il padding verticale invece dell'altezza */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

@media (min-width: 769px){
  .navbar .container{
    position: relative;
  }

  .navbar-nav > .nav-item{
    position: static;
  }

  .navbar-nav > .nav-item > div.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 100%;
  }
}


/* Stile logo e testo del brand */
.logo {
    height: 80px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.brand-text {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1;
}

.fondazione {
    font-size: 0.80em;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0.28em;
}

.surname {
    font-size: 2.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

/* Rettangolino colorato sotto le voci della navbar */
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px; /* Gestisce lo spazio tra i link */
    line-height: normal; /* Usa la line-height di default */
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px; /* Altezza del rettangolo */
    background-color: #459439;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* Allineato al bordo inferiore */
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

/* Rimozione della freccia dropdown */
.nav-link.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown orizzontale */
.dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000033 !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
    min-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.dropdown-item-horizontal:hover {
    color: #d4d4ff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Mostra il menu a tendina al passaggio del mouse */
.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/* Responsive per dispositivi mobili */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>


<!-- Navbar con logo e link -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark mb-0">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
            <img src="img/..." alt="Logo" class="logo">
            <div class="brand-text">
                <span class="fondazione">AAAAAAA</span>
                <span class="surname">XXXX</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="fondazioneDropdown">COMPANY</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-horizontal" aria-labelledby="fondazioneDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 1"> Example 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 2"> Example 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item-horizontal" href="#"><img src="..." alt="Logo 3"> Example 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 6</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 7</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



(Note: To see this embedded preview as intended you may need a desktop computer screen and click on Run Code Snippet, then 'Full page')

I think this is more close to what you want. I've added position:relative to the navbar container to match the width with the inner container, not full-width

I voted your answer. Thank you very much for your kindness and availability. I really appreciate it :)
